# Are all these double integrals of the probability distribution of two continuous random variables equal?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, density-function

If $X$ and $Y$ are two continuous random variables and $A$ and $B$ are any set within the range of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, are all these equal?:

\begin{align*}
P(X \in A,  Y \in B)
&=\int_{X \in A} \int_{Y \in B} f_{XY}(x, y)\,dy\,dx\\
&=  \int_{Y \in B} \int_{X \in A} f_{XY}(x, y)\,dx\,dy\\
&= \int_{X \in A} \int_{Y \in B} f_{XY}(x, y)\,dx\,dy
\end{align*}

Also, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent such that $f_{XY}(x, y) = f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$, then what would $P(X \in A, Y \in B)$ equal?

Comment: None of these integrals makes much sense unless we assume the notation "$X\in\mathcal A$" means just "$\mathcal A$," etc.  Are you perhaps asking whether [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) holds for probability density functions?

Comment: $A$ is some set within $X$ like $A$ could be a range i.e. $A = \{a | a \in X \cap 0 \leq a \leq 5\}$, and just like $B$.

Comment: Understood--but none of the notation makes any mathematical sense.  You use the symbols in ways that are contrary to the usual mathematical and statistical conventions.  I don't think that makes your question incomprehensible, but it does raise some doubts.

Comment: Well given you know what I mean, would you know how to write it in the correct mathematical notation?

Comment: This is what my professor uses, so I just went with that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it should read $\underset{1\{X\in A\}}{\int}\underset{1\{Y\in B\}}{\int}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$ which is a standard notation to be the same as $\int\int1\{X\in A\}1\{Y\in B\}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$ which is the same as the probability in the question. We are just integrating the density over the sets in the probability statement.

Comment: @TyrelStokes Okay but for the third integral, shouldn't the $dx$ and $dy$ be switched i.e. to $dydx$ since the $X \in A$ is in the outer integral and the $Y \in B$ is in the inner integral?

Comment: Yeah, the third integral doesn't make sense to me. The first two are the only two ways I know of expressing this due to Fubini's Theorem. I was just trying to clear up the notation issue so that other people could also weight in!

Comment: @TyrelStokes Okay, thanks! Would you know what the answer to the second part of my question is (involving independence)?

Comment: The nice thing with independence is that the integrals separate.$P(X \in A, Y \in B) = \int\int 1\{X\in A\}1\{Y \in B\}f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy$ $= \int\int 1\{X\in A\}1\{Y \in B\}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)dxdy = \int1\{X\in A\}f_{X}(x)dx \int 1\{Y \in B\}f_{Y}(y)dy = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)$

Comment: @TyrelStokes Oh brilliant, thanks!